# Return 2 lists from one model to a view in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC, and I am struggling with viewmodels. I would like to return 2 lists from the same model into one view.  I will need 2 foreach loops to show records of a different "status" on one view. Because both lists are coming from one model, is it necessary to create a viewmodel?

I have tried the following, but my view is not finding the item type for each list.

```
 public class PipelineViewModel
 {
    public int LeadID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Status{ get; set; }
    public string LoanAgent{ get; set; }

    public List<WebLead> PipeNewLeads { get; set; }
    public List<WebLead> PipeDispLeads { get; set; }
}
```

Note the List is domain model for the table I am pulling the lists from. Is that correct?

Next in my controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string LoanAgent)
    {
        var viewModel = new PipelineViewModel
        {
            PipeNewLeads = db.WebLeads
            .Where(l => l.LoanAgent.Equals(LoanAgent) && l.Status.Equals("New")).ToList(),
             PipeDispLeads = db.WebLeads
            .Where(l => l.LoanAgent.Equals(LoanAgent) && l.Status.Equals("Disp")).ToList(),
         };
        return View(viewModel);
```

I know that the controller is wrong.  I need to be referencing the viewmodel somehow, but I have tried a few ways and keep getting errors.

In the view, I used

```
@model LoanModule.ViewModels.PipelineViewModel
```

and I tried to call each list like this, but it didn't work.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.PipeNewLead)
@foreach (var item in Model.DispNewLead)
```

I think I am almost there, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong in the controller. I would appreciate any help or references!

Comment: You can't bind a collection on postback using a `foreach` loop - you need a `for` loop so the controls are properly named with indexers. But you have not shown the signature of the method your posting to or how you generate the controls.

Comment: I am sorry - I don't understand "signature of the method your posting to or how you generate the controls"

Comment: Are you trying to post some data or is it a display only view? (not clear from what you have shown)

Comment: OK (I misunderstood). You are creating a the view model and returning it to the view correctly. Is the problem that the `PipeNewLeads` and `PipeDispLeads` properties are `null` or empty collections? You say you are getting errors - what errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consdering you have:

```
public ActionResult Index(string LoanAgent)
{
    var viewModel = new PipelineViewModel
    {
        PipeNewLeads = ....
        PipeDispLeads = ....
     };
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Your view `foreach`s should be:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.PipeNewLeads)
@foreach (var item in Model.PipeDispLeads)
```

Note the spelling ;-)

This works perfectly fine for me:

```
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        var viewModel = new PipelineViewModel
        {
            PipeNewLeads = new List<WebLead>(),
            PipeDispLeads = new List<WebLead>(),
        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

And view:

```
@model WebApplication1.Controllers.PipelineViewModel
@foreach (var item in Model.PipeDispLeads)
{
    <p>Disp</p>
}
@foreach (var item in Model.PipeNewLeads)
{
    <p>New</p>
}
```

Your issue is somewhere else.

I would:

1. Look at where you are referencing `IEnumerable<PipelineViewModel>` and find out why. This is most likely in a completely different Razor view, therefore making that error unrelated.
2. Check what your entity framework is returning. The EF error you are getting is probably because either:

   - Database not available
   - EF Model is different to database
   - Login issues
   - Network issues

Obviously your EF error could be something different, but those are some suggestions

Comment: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<LoanModule.ViewModels.PipelineViewModel>' does not contain a definition for 'PipeNewLeads' and no extension method 'PipeNewLeads' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<LoanModule.ViewModels.PipelineViewModel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: and hwere is this error? On the same view?

Double check your `@model` that it is not referencing IEnumerable

Comment: Otherwise post the minimal amount of view that you get this error message

Comment: The s in the view?  Shoot!  Ok.  I added that.

Comment: Still seeing: Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<LoanModule.ViewModels.PipelineViewModel>' does not contain a definition for 'PipeNewLeads' and no extension method 'PipeNewLeads' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<LoanModule.ViewModels.PipelineViewModel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I also tried to run the project and I am getting an error further up in my home controller now: An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: The entity framework exception is completely separate to your ASP.NET error. Your asp.net error you are gettign is because ASP.NET thinks that the @model is an `IEnumerable<PipelineViewModel>`, which obviously does not have the `PipeNewLeads`or `PipeDispLeads` properties

Comment: @Daniela The errors you are seeing do not relate to the code you have shown. Please check and ensure you have posted the real code.

Comment: We would need to see your view in order to figure out why ASP.NET is complaining about it.

Comment: The view is referencing: @model LoanModule.ViewModels.PipelineViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Agent Pipeline";
}

Comment: I have no idea where the second error came from. I will need to spend sometime troubleshooting that.

I define the PipeNewLeads and PipeDispLeads in the viewModel. Does the list type in the view model need to be changed?

      public List<WebLead> PipeNewLeads { get; set; }
      public List<WebLead> PipeDispLeads { get; set; }

Comment: obviously somewhere it is not

Comment: Do you see the error in the Visual Studio debugger, or on the ASP.NET error page in your browser?

Comment: i would suggest you start removing code until you get to the smallest bit that works.

Comment: ASP.net error page in my browser.  maybe is needs something for the code first migrations with the new viewmodel?

Comment: If you still are seeing errors after following the advice in the answer, make sure that you are debugging with your latest code and that IIS isn't using something else.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this issue...I think it's just a typo.

You have `public List<WebLead> PipeNewLeads { get; set; }` in model but `@foreach (var item in Model.PipeNewLead)` in the view. Note the plural, so of course you saw the exceptions your got (not found/does not contain).

Answer (score 0):

You can test to see if you have data from your model in this way:

```
@if(Model.PipeNewLeads != null && Model.PipeNewLeads.Count > 0)
{
      foreach (var item in Model.PipeNewLeads)
      {

      }          
      else
      {
          <p>No PipeNewLeads</p>
      }
 }
```

But you really should be creating Unit Tests where you'd be able to determine which models are actually in your view.